# Django-Haystack with Solr: Searching by page description meta tags

Tags: solr, django-haystack, django-cms

I've been digging around and can't seem to find a way to create a search index for the page description meta tags using Haystack and Solr. Does anyone have experience with this, or any tips?

I have looked at the page model in cms, but can't figure out how to pull the meta tag information for use in the search index.

I am hoping to include this information so that when users search on the site, they will find relevant pages based on what they entered. I thought maybe it would be built in, but so far no luck locating that. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hello, have you considered using https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-search?

Comment: I had looked into aldryn search, but was running into issues with the app-hook, so I had moved on to haystack + solr. At this point, I don't think I have time (right now) to go back and re-work the whole search system. Perhaps when I have more time I'll look more into aldryn again. Thanks for the suggestion though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Turns out the information I was looking for is in the Title model, NOT the page model. The Title model allows you to access all the page title, meta tags, menu titles, etc. So I just created a search index based off of that model and it works like a charm!

See here for the Title model:

[CMS Github](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/models/titlemodels.py)